# Is the use of the word restrained strange in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

Lines of a poem:

> A strong woman is not asked if she is tired, if she is suffering or falling, if she has anxiety or fear, the important thing is that she is always there: a lighthouse in the fog or a rock in the middle of the sea. The strong woman is not forgiven anything. If he loses control he becomes weak, if he loses his temper he becomes hysterical. When the strong woman is missing a minute, it is immediately noticeable, but when she is there, her presence is taken for granted. But the strength that is needed every day, to be that kind of woman, does not matter to anyone. Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be **restrained**, loved and feel that they can *rest*.

The original reads:

> A strong woman is not asked if she is tired, if she is suffering or falling, if she has anxiety or fear, the important thing is that she is always there: a lighthouse in the fog or a rock in the middle of the sea. The strong woman is not forgiven anything. If he loses control he becomes weak, if he loses his temper he becomes hysterical. When the strong woman is missing a minute, it is immediately noticeable, but when she is there, her presence is taken for granted.  But the strength that is needed every day, to be that kind of woman, does not matter to anyone. Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be **pampered**, loved and feel that they can *rest in you*.

When I asked what restrained means here (they only changed words in the last line: *pampered* to *restrained* and *rest in you* to *rest*), the person told me he reads it as restraining from doing/allowing yourself time for yourself. Which sounds weird put in this sentence like this.

I read it like She needs to be restrained (and the why that is so, is missing). Is there a meaning of the word restrained I am missing, or is it a wrong use of this word as I think it is? The newer altered version is going around on social media, but the use of restrained here, just looks odd to me, no idea why they changed that.

Comment: What poem? You need to provide better information. This is impossible.

Comment: Just based on available context, at least Now in the US, women who would identify themselves as "strong" usually want to be unrestrained, and would find constraints to be disrespectful.

Comment: poem: But the strength that is needed every day, to be that kind of woman, does not matter to anyone. 
Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be restrained, loved and feel that they can rest.    and the original is: But the strength that is needed every day, to be that kind of woman, does not matter to anyone. 
Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be pampered, loved and feel that they can rest in you.

Comment: Where did this poem come from and why was anything changed in the first place? *Restrained* does not mean anything like *pampered*. Nor does *rest* mean *rest in you*.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of

> Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be **pampered**, loved and feel that they can **rest in you**.

seems clear. But when this is changed to

> Honor, recognize, respect and thank the strong women in your life, because they also need to be **restrained**, loved and feel that they can **rest**.

any meaning  seems less clear, and certainly not the same as before. I wonder if 'restrained" could possibly be an error for "sustained" which would at least be closer to the original meaning?